# How to generate an Amazon's S3 presigned URL

Tags: delphi, amazon-s3, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm trying to generate presigned URLs for Amazon' S3 objects, but I can't find a GeneratePreSignedUrl class or method on Delphi 10.1 Data.Cloud.AmazonAPI as other languages have. Example on .NET : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html

I have only been able to locate a third-party DLL (Chilkat) that provides this functionality to Delphi : https://www.example-code.com/delphiDll/aws_pre_signed_url_v4.asp but I would prefer to avoid third-party libraries as much as possible (I will keep it as a last resort).

Has anyone generated those URLs using the AmazonAPI provided by Delphi 10.1 ?.

PS: I have to serve files stored on S3, at the moment my Datasnap server retrieves them and returns them to the client as big base64 strings, but the web developer says that he would prefer to just get an URL (the presigned URL to an S3 object).

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Mark.  Have you tried googling `delphi s3 presigned url -chilkat` (to exclude the chilkat examples?  Some if the hits look like they might help.

Comment: Hi Martyn. I didn't know how to exclude a term on a search. Thanks :-). I'm taking a look at the sites I didn't try the first time.